# Is usage @Transactional Annotation Necessary? Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

So I'm new in Spring and currently confused about the `@Transactional` Annotation, I have read a lot of questions and answers about this topic and it seems I still don't get it.

And here is my question:

- Do you need `@Transactional` Annotation when performing insert update delete? when I was trying to prove that, I could still perform insert and update. Do you have any idea why that's happened?
- Is there any performance benefit or issue if you use or do not use `@Transactional` Annotation? Like connection management.
- What will happen if I don't use `@Transactional` Annotation in my program?
- In my experience using `@Transactional`, the update query will be flushed and committed after the method is finished, and I have some cases in which I don't want that to happen. For example:

```
@Transactional
private void doSomething() {
   TransactionEntity te = te.findById("");
   try {
      //fetch using feign and throw customTimCustomTimeoutException 
   } catch (CustomTimeoutException e) {
      te.workflowFailure("doSomething");
      repository.save(te);
   }
   //validation
   //business logic
   //save this save that
   //end of the method and changes will be flushed and committed
}
```

what if at the end of the method, the database goes offline, it will roll back right, and you will lose all your progress right? Even though maybe when in `repository.save(te)` in the catch block statement the database was okay and you don't want to lose that progress. Is there any solution or idea about this?

Answer (score 4):

1. You don't need `@Transactional` for CRUD operations when you use `CrudRepository` interface. All those methods are transactional by default. I guess you were using this one. Check out https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#transactions
2. Performance benefit appears when you mark the method as `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` for the reading methods. Look, for example, at [SimpleJpaRepository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/main/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java).
3. Only CRUD operations are by default transactional. You have to use `@Transactional` in the other cases otherwise you'll get "*java.lang.IllegalStateException: No transactional EntityManager available*".
4. It depends what kind of exception you'll get. If it's runtime you'll get rollback agree. However, if it's a checked exception you can catch it and decide if you want to flush the data anyway. If you have some heavy operations on the DB and you don't want to lose this progress, you can eventually flush multiple times, it depends on the use case.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I was using JpaRepository interface, and when i perform crud it was work perfectly and not giving me that exception. and correct me if im wrong, isnt flush not really commit your progress? what happen if some how, when the method is done, and want to commit, the DB somehow off what going to happen? it will lose all the progress right?

Comment: I have 5th question after the dummy code, do you have any suggestions about that? and I know about the flush, but you suggest I should flush my save ._. and when I asked it, you said its different question... your 4th answer is not solving my problem then

Comment: @jwpol what do you mean by "only CRUD operations are by default transactional"? What are other operations which are not transactional by default? All we do is CRUD right?